# Usb current write protected state

Tags: usb, regedit, read-only, diskpart, write-protect

I have a big problem with my drive because when I try to put anything on it it says that is write protected.I seen that with diskpart would work but nothing,same with regedit.I need help quick with any methods that would work because I need to use the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps carefully:

1. Open **Command Prompt** in Administrator mode.
2. Now type the following and press enter:

   **diskpart**

   **list volume**

   **select volume x** ( Here x is the usb drive that you want to remove write protection. Measure from the capacity, which one is the usb drive. Careful while choosing)

   **attributes disk clear readonly**

   **exit**

If you want to remove write protected by editing Registry, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: This don't work.I tryed the method with registry and diskpart.

Comment: I'm sorry that the **diskpart** didn't work. As you have already tried **registry**, then I can only suggest you another method. Please remember that I have not used this method. One of my friend suggested it. If you want then you may try it.

Comment: The steps are:  1. Download this application from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/664rfnutpp6mb6a/ChipGenius_v4_00_0022_RC3.rar) use it to find your USB's VID and PID.  2. Goto [this](http://flashboot.ru/iflash/) site and search by VID and PID.  3. Search the name of the application you find in the UTILS column and Google it.  4. Click on the first(mostly) link of search list and download the software and save your stick.  Let me know if this works.